# Print a specific line from html file using groovy

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to print the value from HTML file and use this value in my pipeline script in Jenkins but I am unable to print this value

```
def test = new File('copy.html').eachLine(5) { line, number-> 
    println "$number $line"
}
```

copy.html

```
<div class="suite hidden">
  <div class="summary">
    <span class="strong">Specs</span>
    <span>Total: 2</span>
    <span>Passed: 2</span>
    <span>Failed: 0</span>
    <span>Pending: 0</span>
    <span>Disabled: 0</span>
    <span>Duration: 13.6 sec</span>
  </div>
```

I am trying to print the 6th line form this copy.html, i.e "Failed: 0" just need this value, could someone help me here.

Comment: this should work `println new File('copy.html').readLines()[5]` but seems you try to parse a test report. usually there is xml file near by html with test results and it's simpler to parse xml with XmlParser then parsing html...

Comment: thank you. I am using a UIVeri5 (customized test framework) there is no XML file but HTML.

Comment: forgot to update, yes,  readLines() worked for me

Answer (score 0):

As this is an HTML file, it would be better to use any HTML parsing library. You almost always can use **XML Parser** (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) for that:

```
def parser = new XmlParser()
// Here we parsing your file
def report = parser.parse("copy.html");
        
// And here we iterate over all the spans

println "${report.div.div.span[5].text()}"
```

Please look at this tutorial for more information: https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-xml

Of course, XMLParser would not work if HTML you work with is not well-formed XML, but in your example it looks like should work.

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins job run on linux machine, you can use bash to do that

```
def failed = sh(returnStdout: true, 
   script: '''set +x; grep Failed copy.html | sed s,/,, | awk -F '<span>' '{print $2}' ''').trim()

echo failed
```